# Switch classes in Neural Network training in Matlab

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network, classification, prediction

I train a neural network in matlab for binary classification using patternet(). I am surprise to find that if I switch the classes (remember I work with binary classification so only 2 classes) I do not find the inverted probabilities. Here are 2 built examples where the difference is only in the y where the appartenance to classes has been inverted.

```
rng('default')
% case 1:
hiddenLayerSize  = [10];
trainingFct      = 'trainscg';            % possible choice: 'trainscg','trainlm'
errorFcn         = 'crossentropy';
net1              = patternnet(hiddenLayerSize,trainingFct,errorFcn); 

% Set up Division of Data for Training, Validation, Testing
net1.divideParam.trainRatio   = 70/100;
net1.divideParam.valRatio     = 15/100;
net1.divideParam.testRatio    = 15/100;

% Do not show GUI
net1.trainParam.showWindow = false;


X = [5.1,4.9,4.70,4.60,5,5.40,4.60,5,4.40;...
        3.50,3,3.20,3.10,3.60,3.90,3.40,3.40,2.90;...
            1.40,1.40,1.30,1.50,1.40,1.70,1.40,1.50,1.40;...
                0.200,0.200,0.200,0.200,0.200,0.400,0.300,0.200,0.200];

y_1 = [1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0;0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1];
[net1,tr1] = train(net1,X,y_1);
proba1 = net1(X(:,1))



% case 2:
hiddenLayerSize  = [10];
trainingFct      = 'trainscg';            % possible choice: 'trainscg','trainlm'
errorFcn         = 'crossentropy';
net2              = patternnet(hiddenLayerSize,trainingFct,errorFcn); 

% Set up Division of Data for Training, Validation, Testing
net2.divideParam.trainRatio   = 70/100;
net2.divideParam.valRatio     = 15/100;
net2.divideParam.testRatio    = 15/100;

% Do not show GUI
net2.trainParam.showWindow = false;

X = [5.1,4.9,4.70,4.60,5,5.40,4.60,5,4.40;...
        3.50,3,3.20,3.10,3.60,3.90,3.40,3.40,2.90;...
            1.40,1.40,1.30,1.50,1.40,1.70,1.40,1.50,1.40;...
                0.200,0.200,0.200,0.200,0.200,0.400,0.300,0.200,0.200];

y_2 = [0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1;1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0];
[net2,tr2] = train(net2,X,y_2);
proba = net2(X(:,1))
```

Running this code (with the rng('default') for reproducibility)

```
proba1 =

    0.1401
    0.8599


proba2 =

    0.0000
    1.0000
```

Looking at the probabilities in both cases, i am quite surprise to see that the probabilities are not just invereted but totally different. Any suggestion or reason behind this behaviour?

Comment: y_1 and y_2 are different, they should result in different training results.

Comment: Yes they are but we are in a binary classification problem. So why would it be different to switch the label from 1 to -1 or inversely in the training? This should invert the probabilities but not change the actual values.